# how i can disable the appending option when it is selected once in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
  function populate() {
  $('#select_items :selected').each(function() {
    let html = '';
    html += '<div>';
    html +='<label> Quantity:'+$(this).text()+' </label>';
    html += '<input type="text" name="quantity[]" class="form-control" ID="txtName" placeholder="Enter Quantity" required="" val='+$(this).val()+' />';
    html += '</div>'
   
    $('#selected-quantity').append(html)
  })
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="POST" style="width:60%;margin-left:200px">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Choose Product:</label>
    <select name="product_id" class="form-control" class="select" id="select_items" multiple onchange="populate()">
      <option disabled selected>-- Select Product --</option>
      <option value="foo1">foo1</option>
      <option value="foo2">foo2</option>
      <option value="foo3">foo3</option>
      <option value="foo4">foo4</option>
      <option value="foo5">foo5</option>
    </select>
    <div id="selected-quantity">
      
    </div>
  </div>
  <form>
```

i want to disable the selected option when it is already selected.i have tried with the but this didnt work.this is the code where it is appending the dynamically

```
  function populate() {
 $('#select_items :selected').each(function() {
let html = '';
html += '<div>';
html +='<label> '+$(this).text()+' </label>';
html += '<input type="text" name="quantity[]" class="form-control" ID="txtName" placeholder="Enter Quantity" required="" val='+$(this).val()+' />';
html += '</div>' 
$('#selected-quantity').append(html)
});
}
```

here is the code where i tried to disable the selected option

```
 $(document).on('click', 'select.select_items', function () {
  $('select[name*="product_id[]"] option').attr('disabled',false);
  $('select[name*="product_id[]"]').each(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    $('select[name*="product_id[]"]').not($this).find('option').each(function(){
         if($(this).attr('value') == $this.val())
         $(this).attr('disabled',true);
    });
  });
});
```

the CDN use for this is given below

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Since this question is more towards solving the error in jQuery can you please include the HTML markup for `<select>` tag after performing query with PHP?

Comment: i didnt understand about which query you have talked about

Comment: Oh! Apologies. I meant the query for the database. Can you include the HTML markup inside `select` tags?

Comment: obvious the select tag is inside the HTML.

Comment: I mean can you include the output given by PHP inside `select` tag in your question? Hope it is clear... And what is the use of `populate` function?

Comment: @rifky Niyas output is displayed

Comment: Please share more details. How is this question related to PHP, or HTML? If it is not, please remove the tags

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script>
    function populate() {
$('#select_items :selected').each(function() {
  var seldrop = $("#select_items :selected").val();
  if ($("#selectedbox_" + seldrop).length == 0) {
    let html = '';
    html += '<div id="selectedbox_' + seldrop + '">';
    html += '<label> Quantity:' + $(this).text() + ' </label>';
    html += '<input type="text" name="quantity[]" class="form-control" ID="txtName" placeholder="Enter Quantity" required="" val=' + $(this).val() + ' />';
    html += '</div>'
    $('#selected-quantity').append(html)
  } else {
    alert("Already Added");
  }
});
}
</script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">  </script>
```

Check Append Div length exists or not

> $("#selectedbox_" + seldrop).length == 0

```
<form method="POST" style="width:60%;margin-left:200px">
<div class="form-group">
<label>Choose Product:</label>
<select name="product_id" class="form-control" class="select" id="select_items" multiple onchange="populate()">
  <option value="0" disabled selected>-- Select Product --</option>
  <option value="foo1">foo1</option>
  <option value="foo2">foo2</option>
  <option value="foo3">foo3</option>
  <option value="foo4">foo4</option>
  <option value="foo5">foo5</option>
</select>
<div id="selected-quantity">

</div>
</div>
<form>
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Comment: @bBasant Singh thanks alot this give me the actual result rather than disabling the selected option.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

You are using `select_items` as class. But it is id.

Added working fiddle link also.

[Working fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/bqa7fehj/1/)

```
var selectedVal = [];

$(document).on('click', '#select_items option:selected', function () {
    $("select option[value='"+$(this).val()+"']").attr('disabled', true); 
});

function populate() {
    $('#select_items :selected').each(function() {
        let html = '';
        html += '<div>';
        html +='<label> '+$(this).text()+' </label>';
        html += '<input type="text" name="quantity[]" class="form-control" ID="txtName" placeholder="Enter Quantity" required="" val='+$(this).val()+' />';
        html += '</div>' 
        $('#selected-quantity').append(html)
    });
}
```

Comment: thanks its working but this code effects my whole code on inserting selected data into databse

Comment: check the fiddle link. there is javascript variable `selectedVal`. It will contain all values. You can pass that value to backend.

Comment: ooh my bad i forgot about it